# GitHub Actions: Which permissions must be assigned to GITHUB_TOKEN used by the SonarScanner?

Tags: sonarqube, github-actions

According to the [SonarQube GitHub Integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/github-integration/) documentation the `GITHUB_TOKEN` must be injected as environment variable when SonarScanner is executed.

```yaml
- name: Build and analyze
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
    SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
  run: mvn -B verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar
```

I would like to grant the minimal required permissions. Which permissions I should grant to the token?

[Permissions for the `GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#permissions-for-the-github_token).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism is quite confusing for me. At the beginning, I didn't add the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable at all. My pull requests were successfully built, but the analysis of the main branch started failing. I configured token to set permissions manually and didn't grant any permissions (I omitted the `permissions` key in the workflow file). The built has been finished successfully. Currently my configuration looks like this:

```
jobs:
  Build:
    # ...
    permissions:
      checks: write
    steps:
      # ...
      - name: Execute SonarScanner
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: ${{ env.MAVEN_CMD }} sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

The `checks: write` permission is required by a different action (`scacap/action-surefire-report@v1`) used in the workflow. To be honest I have no idea why the GitHub token is needed, but with this minimal configuration it works for me.

---

**TL;DR**: It looks for me that the token must be set, but it doesn't require any permissions.